# Create Video out of image files?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, video, sdk, jpeg

I'm trying to make a video out of a folder full of jpeg files. I tried Google, and everybody is stuck with this. I have downloaded the WM SDK and the Encoder, but since the moment I don't know their object model I cant do much.

Does somebody here have some code WORKING about how to create a WMV or an AVI or a MPEG video file out of a folder full of jpegs? (In C#)

**I can see on the answers that apparently there is no way to do it from C#, just using a third party. I will check your suggestions.**

Comment: Do you want one image per frame, or is it more of a slideshow?

Comment: I would like to make a slideshow.

Comment: So you want to create a video file which will be of a slideshow of images?

Comment: Yes. Is that possible? I have screenshots taken with an application and I want to recreate the interaction as a video.
Is that possible?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Corinna John's AVIFile wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx). I used it in the [AVI output plugin for Cropper](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3303#47968).

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is capable of making a video out of several image files. [Here's](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=34) a quite overview of how to do it.

FFMPEG, as CptSkippy mentioned, also has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

See the [AVBlocks Slideshow sample](https://bitbucket.org/primosoftware/avblocks-samples/src/default/windows/net/samples/Slideshow). It creates a video (like MP4) from images. The input is a series of JPEG images. The output is configured with an AVBlocks preset.

Answer (score 2):

Try via NuGet "accord.extensions.imaging.io", then I wrote the following little function:

```
    private void makeAvi(string imageInputfolderName, string outVideoFileName, float fps = 12.0f, string imgSearchPattern = "*.png")
    {   // reads all images in folder 
        VideoWriter w = new VideoWriter(outVideoFileName, 
            new Accord.Extensions.Size(480, 640), fps, true);
        Accord.Extensions.Imaging.ImageDirectoryReader ir = 
            new ImageDirectoryReader(imageInputfolderName, imgSearchPattern);
        while (ir.Position < ir.Length)
        {
            IImage i = ir.Read();
            w.Write(i);
        }
        w.Close();
    }
```

It reads all images from a folder and makes a video out of them.

If you want to make it nicer you could probably read the image dimensions instead of hard coding, but you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [FFMPEG](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)?  I've used it to create thumbnails from video in several projects.

Answer (score 1):

I finally settled on [Splicer](http://www.codeplex.com/splicer).  Free, simple to use, and it works.  More info at [Working way to make video from images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c)