# Stream video to network in h.264 format in C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, video-processing

I need two things to be done:

1. Create a video from the images (jpeg) which are placed in a folder and
2. Encode this video to h.264 format and stream to the network.

Right now I am sending each image files to the network and receiving it on the server and then displaying it there. This gives an illusion of video playback but in actual it is only images which are displayed one after another.

I just need to convert this images group to the video of h.264 format and stream it to the network.

Comment: Are you creating a stream here? Or just streaming a file created from the JPGS?

Comment: Video _is_ displaying seperate images one after another and creating an illusion that it's not ;)

Comment: @Nick, I am just streaming each jpg files. Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Working way to make video from images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c)