# Way to generate video from a bunch of images?

Tags: .net, video, graphics

Can anybody tell me the way of generating the video from the bunch of images(bitmap).
May be open format of avi file or open-source library,

I used Splicer but it has some bugs in production using.

The BytesCount [Image To Video SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/imagetovideosdk/imagetovideosdk.html) is best choice but it is commerce solution.

Do you now any alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c. Solutions include Splicer and VideoLan.

Comment: Do you want to stuff them into a file, or instead make available as video for processing/presentation purposes?

Comment: For first time, I need to generate video. Generally I have a timeline images. It's needed to visualize it just combining.

Answer (score 3):

We have used [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and achieved professional results.

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and
> stream audio and video.

Also...

> FFmpeg is free software licensed under the LGPL or GPL depending on
> your choice of configuration options. If you use FFmpeg or its
> constituent libraries, you must adhere to the terms of the license in
> question. You can find basic compliance information and get licensing
> help on our [license and legal considerations page](http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html).

From the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion):

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi

Comment: I've had a lot of success using the ffmpeg CLI from various languages.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but the CodeProject article [A Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx) seems to have what you need, specifically it does the following things:

- Read images from the video stream.
- Decompress a compressed video stream.
- Compress an uncompressed video stream.
- Change the compression of a video stream.
- Export the video stream into a separate .avi file.
- Export the audio stream into a .wav file.
- Copy a couple of seconds from audio and video stream into a new .avi file.
- Add sound from a .wav file to the video.
- Create a new video stream from a list of bitmaps.
- Add frames to an existing video stream, compressed or not.
- Insert frames into a stream.
- Copy or delete frames from a stream.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question with DirectShow API. Windows SDK comes with [Push Source Filters Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which introduce video generation in native code. Having video generated, you can use the filter in DirectShow pipeline to visualize the sequence and/or write into files (compress video, attach audio etc).

The samples are not directly convertable into managed code domain, but you still have options there. Check these threads out regarding the related discussions:

- [C# version of the PushSource example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/410d5bb2-d0b1-4574-be53-340e02a778df)
- [Push samples (bitmaps) in DirectShow graph](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/f40f569e-38de-4c7a-b276-59fefae0683b)
- [GSSF sample in http://DirectShowNet.SourceForge.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/)