# How can I generate video dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert a series of PNG files into a video animation (avi or mpeg). Can this be achieved with C# in asp.net?

Comment: The short answer would be "yes" - not that I've done it but there is no logical reason why it couldn't be done. A more important question is what are you trying to achieve? As I read your question I'm thinking slideshow of user-uploaded images - for tasks like that I'm not sure video is the right format.

Comment: @mbanzon - That's so close to my own thought process it's scary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at the [Splicer Project](http://splicer.codeplex.com/). You might also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c-sharp) previous SO thread for more information.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET isn't a tool designed for generating avi or mpegs from images.  You'd be better off with a tool (open source or commercial) specifically designed for such a task.

It can be done in .NET, but in my personal opinion, the effort isn't worth the outcome.  The ROI just isn't there when so many good tools already exist.

However, if you're looking to build a slide show, then you can use the [SlideShowExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/SlideShow/SlideShow.aspx) in the Ajax Control Toolkit.