# Record video from opengl

Tags: c#, opengl, video, tao-framework

I am using Tao framework and I have a simple opengl control.
How can I record a video from this control and save it to a file?

Comment: Is there any example? I can take pictures but how convert them to a video file?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Bart : Good, but is there any better way? I mean without taking pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/step-by-step-to-create-a-desktop-video-recorder-in-c/) for a link that mentions both Bitmap screen capture in C# and starts to describe the AVI conversion.

For further information about the library used to in the first link to make an avi file from a collection of bitmap images see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library).

See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/satisharveti/enhanced-desktop-recorder-in-net-using-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/) for an example that uses the Media Player Encoder in order record the screen.

The more complicated and direct way would be to either use a video capture card or write a software device that emulates one and feed that source to DirectShow filter using DirectShow.Net or Pinvoking other DirectShow libaries directly.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I record a video from this control and save it to a file?

Use glReadPixels to get the pixel data. Feed the pixel data into a video encoder (e.g. a DirectShow filter graph, or through ffmpeg/libavcodec or sump the images into files and encode them to video later).

Comment: Yes, I used Gl.glReadPixels to capture an image, but I'm looking for a better way to record video, but it seems there is not and I have to use something like ffmpeg